# Setting documents folder as a network public folder from cmd in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rights-management

I am trying to create a batch file for setting the user documents folder in Windows so that it is accessible from the network like the public folder is by default, pretty much making it shared with everybody.

I can't figure out the syntax for it, though. So far tried messing with [cacls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) but without any luck.

I am testing it on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
net share "My files=%USERPROFILE%\Documents"
```